# English translation of Russian text in My Way

Tags: translation

In the Korean movie "My Way", which takes place during World War II, a group of Japanese soldiers were taken prisoner by the Soviet Red Army after the Battle of Khalkhin Gol. In the prison camp to which they were sent, a soldier in the Red Army read out loud, in Japanese, to the captured Japanese prisoners from a paper written in Russian, which is shown in the screenshot below. What is the English translation of the text?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Oath
>
> First, this is not a war prisoners camp, but a working camp.
>
> Second, we are not war prisoners, we are war criminals who imposed the
>   war.
>
> Third, we are obliged to repay our debts to the Soviet Union  with our
>   selfless work and changing our ideology.